# ListView strange exception

Tags: c#, listview, compact-framework, windows-ce

Windows CE 5.0, NET Compact framework 3.5

I have faced with a very strange behavior of the ListView control. I extended the ListView control as below:

```
public partial class MyListView : ListView
{
  public void Fill(IEnumerable<string[]> data)
  {
    BeginUpdate();
    Items.Clear();
    foreach (var d in data) {
      Items.Add(new ListViewItem(d));
    }
    EndUpdate();
  }
}
```

And I have two similar devices with the same OS image. This code works fine with the first device, but it throws an exception at **Items.Add** with the second one. The exception does not appears each time, but very often.
I cannot understand where is a problem. Do you have any ideas why that happen?

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled   Message="Exception" StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.AGL.Common.MISC.HandleAr(PAL_ERROR ar)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ListView.ntvGetColumnHeaderWidth(Int32 iColumn)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader.get_Width()
       at System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem.Actualize(Int32 index)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem.ListViewSubItemCollection.Actualize()
       at System.Windows.Forms.ListView.ListViewItemCollection.Insert(Int32 index, ListViewItem listViewItem)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ListView.ListViewItemCollection.Add(ListViewItem listViewItem)
       at MyNamespace.MyListView.Fill(IEnumerable`1 data)
```

Some times I get an exception like this:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled
  Message="Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.\r\nParameter name: index"
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem.Actualize(Int32 index)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem.ListViewSubItemCollection.Actualize()
       at System.Windows.Forms.ListView.ListViewItemCollection.Insert(Int32 index, ListViewItem listViewItem)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ListView.ListViewItemCollection.Add(ListViewItem listViewItem)
```

Comment: How many items do you have? How long is the string you're inserting?

Comment: If you see strange probs/exceptions on one device and not on others, you should start from scracth and clean boot or wipe the faulty one. Sometimes you may need to reflash the unit. Asone starts programming/debugging/playing with a device he/she might corrupt the object store.

Answer (score 0):

These two lines suggest me that could be a problem with the headers of the ListView, did you fill it or defined it before add the items?

```
   at System.Windows.Forms.ListView.ntvGetColumnHeaderWidth(Int32 iColumn)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader.get_Width()
```